# Pattern matching with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

My server dev gave me a regex that he says is the requirement for user name. It is `@"^\w+([\s-]\w+)*$"`

I need help figuring out right Java expression for this. It is confusing since I need to put some escape characters to make compiler happy.

I am trying this. Please let me know if this is right :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+([\\s-]\\w+)*\\$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

   Matcher m = p.matcher(username);

   if ((username.length() < 3 ) || (m.find())) {
      log ("Invalid pattern"); 
      return false;
   }
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct pattern is `"^\\w+([\\s-]\\w+)*$"`.

`$` denotes the end of the string, if you use `\\$` it will force the string to have the char `$` and that's not the intent.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is this regex actually saying ? I understand \w is a word. So, does it mean, a name will be [word] optional : - or space or * followed by another word ?

Comment: should john*  be a valid name then ?

Comment: `^` is the beginning of the string, that should have at least one (`+`) word char (`\w` -> a-z or 0-9) followed by zero or more (`*`) occurrences of a space char (`\s`) or a dash (`-`) followed by at least one (`+`) word char (`\w`).

Comment: thanks. So, john* (john followed by asterix)  is invalid then ?

Comment: `john*` is invalid in your case.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex

```
^\\w+([\\s-]\\w+)*\\$
                    ^
```

You don't have to escape this `$`. It is there to indicate End Of Line.

so the correct Regex would be:

```
^\\w+([\\s-]\\w+)*$
```

*N.B.: However, you have to make sure that this `$` sign doesn't represent `$` literally. In that case you'd have to escape it, but I anticipate in that case it would be escaped in your source RegEx as well.*

Comment: thanks for the additional clarification. The name didnt require an explicit dollar sign. I guess this is just a end marker of the name.

Comment: @techtinkerer ya. I think in that case you should use RegEx `^\\w+([\\s-]\\w+)*$`